# Why is useState not updating state with the keydown handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple React image slider, where the right/left arrow keys slides through the images.

### Problem

When I press the right arrow ONCE, it works as expected. The id updates from 0 to 1, and re-renders the new image.

When I press the right arrow a SECOND time, I see (through console.log) that it registers the keystroke, but doesn't update the state via `setstartId`.

Why?

Also, I am printing `new StartId: 0` in the component function itself. I see that when you first render the page, it prints it 4 times. Why? Is it: 1 for the initial load, 2 for the two useEffects, and a last one when the promises resolve?

### The Code

Here is my sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-carousel-yv7njm?file=/src/App.js

```js
export default function App(props) {
  const [pokemonUrls, setPokemonUrls] = useState([]);
  const [startId, setStartId] = useState(0);
  const [endId, setEndId] = useState(0);

  console.log(`new startId: ${startId}`)

  const handleKeyStroke = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      // GO LEFT
      case 37:
        break;
      // GO RIGHT
      case 39:
        console.log("RIGHT", startId);
        setStartId(startId + 1);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPokemonById(id) {
      const response = await fetch(`${POKE_API_URL}/${id}`);
      const result = await response.json();
      return result.sprites.front_shiny;
    }

    async function fetchNpokemon(n) {
      let pokemon = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const pokemonUrl = await fetchPokemonById(i + 1);
        pokemon.push(pokemonUrl);
      }
      setPokemonUrls(pokemon);
    }

    fetchNpokemon(5);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyStroke);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyStroke);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel pokemonUrls={pokemonUrls} startId={startId} />
      <div id="carousel" onKeyDown={handleKeyStroke}>
        <img alt="pokemon" src={pokemonUrls[startId]} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: not read much but you add your addEventListener to window not carousel in useEffect.

Comment: While trying it on codepen, the code worked perfectly. (When I tested it the useEffect() hook was commented out but on uncommenting it it worked like a charm)

Comment: Just a side comment, but your code is really easy to read.  Well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by following either approach:

1. Add handleKeyStroke in the dependency array of useEffect. Wrap `handleKeyStroke()` with `useCallback` hook and add `startId` inside dependency array of useCallback. So, whenever `startId` changes, useCallback will recreate handleKeyStroke and useEffect will get a new version of handleKeyStroke
2. Inside `handleKeyStroke()` call `setStartId(prev=>prev+1)` (recommended)

Updated `handleKeyStroke()`

```
 const handleKeyStroke = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      // GO LEFT
      case 37:
        break;
      // GO RIGHT
      case 39:
        console.log("RIGHT", startId);
        setStartId(prev=>prev + 1);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

**Explanantion**

In the code above, you're adding `window.addEventListener` inside useEffect with empty dependency array. And inside `handleKeyStroke()`, you are setting the state this way `setStartId(startId + 1);`.

Because of the useEffect with empty dependency array, when `handleKeyStroke()` is initialized, it is initialized with values which are available on mount. It doesn't access the updated state.

So, for example, when you call `setStartId(startId + 1);`, `handleKeyStroke()` has the value of startId=0 and it adds 1 to it.
But next time when you call `setStartId(startId + 1);`, the `startId` value is still 0 inside `handleKeyStroke()` because it's value has been saved in useEffect because of empty dependency array. But when we use callback syntax it has access to previous state. And we won't need to anything inside useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Can you explain why a callback is better here?

Comment: @tbd_ I've added explanation in my answer, let me know if you've any doubts.

Comment: Ahh, I got it! I did notice that the `handleKeyDown` fn had stale `startId` data. Follow up q: does this mean that anytime you pass a callback to a state setter like `setStartId`, it inherently holds the prev component state? `setStartId(prevId=>prevId+1)`

Comment: @tbd_ The value is received by the callback at the time function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with @Inder's answer.

I made a few mistakes:

- Updated the state setter to use a callback instead. Not sure why that works, I will do some research (eg. `setStartId(id=>id+1)` instead of `setStartId(startId+1)`)
- Used the div's onKeyDown prop instead of `window.addEventListener`. That is how react expects you to bind event listeners to elements.
- `onKeyDown` doesn't work on divs by default, because it doesn't expect any inputs (unlike `<input />`). But if you add `tabIndex=0` to it, it allows you to focus on the div, and therefore enables the `onKeyDown` listener on it.

Here is the final code:

```js
const POKE_API_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";

const Carousel = ({ handleKeyDown, pokemonUrls, startId }) => (
  <div tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
    <img alt="pokemon" src={pokemonUrls[startId]} />
  </div>
);

export default function App(props) {
  const [pokemonUrls, setPokemonUrls] = useState([]);
  const [startId, setStartId] = useState(0);
  const [endId, setEndId] = useState(0);

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      // GO LEFT
      case 37:
        if (startId - 1 >= 0) {
          setStartId((prev) => prev - 1);
        }
        break;
      // GO RIGHT
      case 39:
        if (startId < pokemonUrls.length - 1) {
          setStartId((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPokemonById(id) {
      const response = await fetch(`${POKE_API_URL}/${id}`);
      const result = await response.json();
      return result.sprites.front_shiny;
    }

    async function fetchNpokemon(n) {
      let pokemon = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const pokemonUrl = await fetchPokemonById(i + 1);
        pokemon.push(pokemonUrl);
      }
      setPokemonUrls(pokemon);
    }

    fetchNpokemon(5);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel
        handleKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        pokemonUrls={pokemonUrls}
        startId={startId}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```